# Use of case statement within where clause with two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Any suggestions/thoughts on how to filter the rows from the below table when the following condition is applied would be great. Thanks in advance

*Condition 1:* when the `Effective_date` is 08/01/2017 or prior, then I need to all the ID's when their `UABP` is either NULL/Blank/any non-zero value/ zero

*Condition 2:* when the `Effective_date > 08/01/2017`, then I need to apply a filter and select only the ID's that have their `UABP > 0` and omit other records.

Initial query:

Note: I included in the UABP and Eff_date column in the result table to show the idea of its data, but I don't want them in my query

```
SELECT 
    MAX(id_num) [ID], Submission_Num 
FROM 
    [Fiduciary] 
GROUP BY 
    Submission_Num
```

Modified query but not able to get the expected result :

```
--edited corrected one for fidicuary standalone when effective date greater than 08/01
SELECT 
    MAX(id_num) [ID], Submission_Num 
FROM 
    [Fiduciary] 
WHERE
    UABP <> '' OR UABP IS NOT NULL OR UABP <> 0 
    AND  Effective_Date >  '08/1/2017'
GROUP BY 
    Submission_Num
```

Original table

```
+---+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+
|ID |    Submission_Num  | UABP        | Effective_date  |
+---+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 1 | 12121121           | NULL        |  07/1/2017      | 
| 2 | 65662656           | 565         |  06/1/2017      |   
| 6 | 24646426           |             |  05/1/2017      |    
| 3 | 12652354           | 0           |  06/1/2017      |      
| 8 | 56566565           | 232         |  08/02/2017     |   
| 9 | 65665656           | NULL        |  08/02/2017     | 
| 10| 76358928           | 0           |  09/02/2017     | 
+---+--------------------+-------------+---------------- +
```

Expected results:

```
+---+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+
|ID |    Submission_Num  | UABP        | Effective_date  |
+---+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 1 | 12121121           | NULL        |  07/1/2017      | 
| 2 | 65662656           | 565         |  06/1/2017      |   
| 6 | 24646426           |             |  05/1/2017      |    
| 3 | 12652354           | 0           |  06/1/2017      |      
| 8 | 56566565           | 232         |  08/02/2017     |   
+---+--------------------+-------------+---------------- +
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, I think I have your criteria down right, but I was not quite following your UABP being zero or not zero, so you might need to change that one to fit your solution.

```
SELECT Max(id_num) [ID], Submission_Num FROM [Fiduciary] 
WHERE Effective_Date <= '08/1/2017' AND UABP = '' 
   OR Effective_Date <= '08/1/2017' AND UABP IS NULL 
   OR Effective_Date <= '08/1/2017' AND UABP >= 0 
OR    Effective_Date > '08/1/2017' AND UABP > 0
GROUP BY Submission_Num
ORDER BY Submission_Num
```

The point is, I broke it down into multiple sets of OR/AND statements.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it

```
SELECT Max(id_num) [ID], Submission_Num FROM [Fiduciary] 
where Effective_Date <= '08/1/2017' or Effective_Date >  '08/1/2017' and UABP>0
GROUP BY Submission_Num
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write the query as:

```
SELECT Max(id_num) as ID, Submission_Num
FROM [Fiduciary] f
WHERE (Effective_Date < '2017-08-01' AND
       (UABP IS NULL OR USABP IN (0)
      ) OR
      (Effective_Date >= '2017-08-01' AND
       UABP > 0
      ) ;
```

I'm not not sure if `UABP` is a number or string based on your description of the problem. If a string, then put single quotes around the constants.